# Tokenize string on multiple characters in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsstring, tokenize

I am trying to build a string tokenizer that can tokenize on mutilple characters.

I know I can use:

> [string componentsSeparatedByString:@"-"];

but I want to check for white space, dashes, and newlines.

How can this be done?

Comment: Unless this is an exercise, you should look into using [ParseKit](http://parsekit.com/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use:

```
  [string componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString: @"\n\t "]]
```

Answer (score 1):

As Ahmed suggested, use `NSCharacterSet` to define the delimiter characters, as shown below:

```
NSString *s = @"foo\nbar baz-quux";

NSMutableCharacterSet *characterSet = [NSMutableCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet];
[characterSet addCharactersInString:@"-"];

NSArray *strings = [s componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:characterSet];
```